# C: Pause a process by pressing p, instead of Ctrl +Z

Tags: c, signals

Is it possible to pause a thread/process by pressing a button on the keyboard, such as "P", and resume the process by pressing "R" instead of Ctrl+Z?

My attempt is as follow:

```
int sig_pause = 0; // define global variable 
....


void* thread_function (void *ptr)
{
    ....
    while(sig_flag) usleep(100); // wait if sig_flag is 1
}



/* pause function */
void pause_handler(int sig)
{
    if(sig==SIGTSTP)  sig_pause=1-sig_pause;
}



int main(void){
....
signal(SIGTSTP, pause_handler);
}
```

Above method works fine by pressing ctrl + z, but I don't know how to customize it to my key press.

Comment: That "customization" has nothing to with your program, it's all about the terminal program.

Comment: what do you mean terminal program, can you guide me to find the solution? I need to find a way to handle interrupt the process by pressing a P.

Comment: emulator of terminal, terminal itself or anything that handle the execution of your program.

Comment: When you open a command-line window you usually open a program called "Terminal" or similar. *That* program. Check its menus and settings if it's possible.

Comment: Thanks.  I am using Linux terminal, I will check that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because signal only traps very specific signals being sent to the program thread, typically through the operating system or from another process. Standard C doesn't really have a way to do it for any keyboard input. What you need is a keyboard listener and it needs to be bound to the window that's running the process. Oftentimes that does not include the console and I couldn't find anything when I was looking around. If you had a GUI of some kind, you would probably use a thread or at least some of the GUI library's event functions for it.

You might be able to use threading to have another thread calling some modified function on repeat that has a shared memory access to a flag you can use to pause the program. That thread can handle the potentially blocking standard input calls and if you can find code that works on your operating system and compiles that makes sure the call isn't blocking and doesn't require an 'enter' press that might work. You just shouldn't or can't have multiple things trying to read from standard input at the same time.

That's about all I can think of anyway.

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-c-2/

You could create a thread that has a function with an infinite loop that does the waiting stuff and captures your input. Just don't call join on it. (You want to let it run.) Then all you need is a state machine based on the input and that static variable or 'flag.'

Comment: I tried to create a new thread and uses "scanf ("%c", &input);" to capture the user input, but it does require an 'Enter' input. Usually, the typed ''P" disappears before I press 'enter', because the update of the output is faster.